# List of supported data types for dimensions in Druid?

Tags: types, distributed-computing, druid

I cannot seem to find any particular tutorial/doc page on the Druid website which has a list of all supported data types in Druid for the dimensions. From how much I've read, I know that `long, float` and `string` are definitely supported, but I have next to zero information about the other supported types.

Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Druid natively supports five basic column types: "long" (64 bit signed
> int), "float" (32 bit float), "double" (64 bit float) "string" (UTF-8
> encoded strings), and "complex" (catch-all for more exotic data types
> like hyperUnique and approxHistogram columns). Timestamps (including
> the __time column) are stored as longs, with the value being the
> number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

I found this page that contains a list of supported types:
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html#data-types

Answer (score 2):

Dimensions are fields that can be filtered on or grouped by. They are always single Strings, arrays of Strings, single Longs, single Doubles or single Floats.